# I have Android Studio installed, but I am unable to access gradle through command line

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have Android Studio installed, but I am unable to access gradle through command line.

```
gradle --version
gradle: command not found
```

Do I have to install it separately in if I want to use gradle for java projects or am I missing it because I haven't added to the path etc?

Comment: There is **NO** command line tool called `gradle`. There is a scripting file called `gradlew` that gets created in your project root, that can launch the `gradle` based java programs tailored to each project.

Answer (score 2):

It's because gradle is not installed globally or not in your **PATH** environment variable.

You can use gradle wrapper which is located at the project root.
Move to project dir and run `./gradlew --version`

Answer (score 1):

> If all you want to do is run an existing Gradle build, then you don’t need to install Gradle if the build has a [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#gradle_wrapper), identifiable via the gradlew and/or gradlew.bat files in the root of the build. You just need to make sure your system [satisfies Gradle’s prerequisites](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#sec:prerequisites).
>
> Android Studio comes with a working installation of Gradle, so you don’t need to install Gradle separately in that case.
>
> In order to create a new build or add a Wrapper to an existing build, you will need to install Gradle [according to these instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#installation).

from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/getting_started.html#gs:installation

Since I want to use gradle globally to make a Java library (not Android) I ended up installing a separate copy of gradle using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) since I use SDKMAN! to manage multiple Java versions on my system already:

```sh
sdk install gradle
```

Although, gradle should be available on many other package managers as well.